# pass из Python в PHP и JS

Tags: javascript, php, python

Есть ли аналоги `pass` из Python в языках PHP и JavaScript. Хочу сделать конструкцию `try ... catch ...`, что бы случае если все было нормально т.е `try` то коды выполнялся. Если же `catch` то код работал дальше.

Comment: VS Code помог мне в PHP `try { ... } catch (\Throwable $th) {}`, а что качается JS, то вроде как можно использовать вот такое вот `// pass` [источник](https://qastack.ru/programming/33383840/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-for-the-python-pass-statement-that-does-nothing)

Comment: Вы наверное не до конца знакомы, для чего pass используется в Python. pass = {}, т.е. блоку, который ничего не делает. А так как в питоне фигурных кавычек нету, то ввели эту инструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ:

Инструкция  питона `pass` - это эквивалент пустой конструкции`{}` (не путать с объявлением объектов) как в PHP так и в JavaScript.

А `try ... catch` по сути одинаковые

```
try:
    pass
except:
    pass

// PHP и JS
try {} catch {}
```

Comment: Дополню - в пайтоне нельзя использовать пустую строку из-за отступов - программа "думает", что следующая строка это часть этой (естественно, без этих пробелов) и выдаёт ошибку отступов.